# How to sort a numpy array using another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have tried to convert my array to a 2-D array and utilizing `np.sort` and `np.lexsort` but have not had any luck.

```py
import numpy as np

# Here are the 2 arrays I would like to sort b using a.
a = np.array([6,5,3,4,1,2])
b = np.array(["x","y","z","a","b","c"])
```

Is it possible to sort b using a?

When printing b the output should be:

```
["b", "c", "z", "a", "y", "x"]
```

Comment: Have you looked at `np.argsort`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in NumPy indexing:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...:
   ...: # Here are the 2 arrays I would like to sort b using a.
   ...: a = np.array([6,5,3,4,1,2])
   ...: b = np.array(["x","y","z","a","b","c"])

In [2]: b[a - 1]
Out[2]: array(['c', 'b', 'z', 'a', 'x', 'y'], dtype='<U1')
```

Also, I think your desired output is `c, b, z, a, y, x` instead of `b, c, z, a, y, x`.

Comment: "Also, I think your desired output is `c, b, z, a, y, x` instead of `b, c, z, a, y, x`." - you probably think that because you're thinking of the operation "take element `result[i]` from the index of `b` given by `a[i]`", while the questioner is thinking of the dual operation "put `b[i]` in the cell of `result` given by `a[i]`", or the operation "take the permutation that would sort `a` and apply that permutation to `b`". Those operations would produce `b, c, z, a, y, x`.

Comment: Hey @tomothy32 thanks for the help. I did mean for it to be b, c, z, a, y, x.
as that is the order if it were sorted by a. does that seem correct?